# ¿Cómo hacer búsquedas con combianción de palabras en varias tablas?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo en el controlador la consulta y los JOINS:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $search = $request->get('search');

    $accommodations = Accommodation::search($request->search)
                    ->join("cities","cities.id","=","accommodations.city_id")
                    ->join("regions","regions.id","=","cities.region_id")
                    ->join("provinces","provinces.id","=","cities.province_id")
                    ->join("users","users.id","=","accommodations.user_id")
                    ->paginate(12);

    return view('admin/accommodations/index', compact('accommodations'));

}
```

Luego el Query Scope:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
{
    if (trim($search) != "")
        return $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', street, ' ', city, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', price, ' ', province, ' ', region)"), "LIKE", "%$search%");
}
```

Las búsquedas me funcionan bien, mientras consulto individualmente, ejemplo: Miramar, San Isidro, etc... Los busca en el campo City

O sí busco: La provincia, por alguna palabra que componga el titulo por precio, etc... Individualmente, pero necesito poder escribir: Posadas en Miramar y que me haga la búsqueda de coincidencias en ambos campos, city y title

¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

PD: en un cuadro de texto (Input) llamado search obtengo lo que el usuario escribe, y en base a ello se realiza la búsqueda.

------------------ Editado --------------------

Modifiqué mi scope y me funciona pero las palabras deben ser precisas para que encuentre los resultados (tal como están en la base de datos), si está en sigular la palabra en la BD la encuentra de esa manera, pero no en plural, además con oraciones como: posada en miramar (funciona) pero con: posada en buenos aires (no) usando el "EN" con más de dos palabras posteriores no funciona, probé con "orWhere" pero no lo soluciona.

Scope:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

        $array = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {

         $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', street, ' ', city, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', price, ' ', province, ' ', region)"), "LIKE", "%$search[$i]%");

        }

        return $array;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez, una buena forma de abordar esto sería agregando los filtros directamente sobre tu query. Por ejemplo:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

   $search = $request->get('search');
   $accommodations = Accommodation::search($request->search)
                ->join("cities","cities.id","=","accommodations.city_id")
                ->join("regions","regions.id","=","cities.region_id")
                ->join("provinces","provinces.id","=","cities.province_id")
                ->join("users","users.id","=","accommodations.user_id");

   if($search) {
       $accommodations = $accommodations
                  ->where('nombre_tabla.city', 'like', $search)
                  ->orWhere('nombre_tabla.title', 'like', $search);

   }

   $accommodations = $accommodations->get()->paginate(12);


   return view('admin/accommodations/index', compact('accommodations'));

}
```

Esta forma de hacerlo creo que hace el código más claro y manejable. Si no le envías parámetros de búsqueda trabajara sobre todos los registros, pero si le mandas los parámetros de búsqueda será mucho más eficiente. Debes considerar que buscar sobre concatenaciones es es más costoso, y al manejar un alto volumen de datos puede volverse inmantenible.

De esta forma también podrías ir añadiendo nuevos criterios de búsqueda de manera más simple e intuitiva. 
Esto dará resultados mucho mejores si los campos city y title (y todos aquellos sobre los que quieras buscar) están indexados en la base de datos.

Espero aportar

Comment: Gracias por responder, funciona igual que la forma que la tengo.

Answer (score 0):

Volví a leer tu problema y creo que se me ocurrió una forma para abordarlo.
Primero que todo te cuento lo que entendí. Una persona va a buscar una frase, pero de esa frase hay palabras que pertenecen a un campo en la base de datos, y otras palabras a otro campo. Si es así, la única solución que veo es que separes las palabras de la frase de búsqueda.

Por ejemplo:

```
$palabras_search = explode(" ", $search);
```

Entonces podrías iterarlas con un foreach y por cada palabra ir agregando los filtros where/orWhere para ver si existen en una u otra columna.

Claro, para que funcione, cada iteración en sí misma debe ser un "OR", porque podrán poner palabras que no estén. Me explico: Si yo busco,por ejemplo, "Restaurant en Ciudad1" el campo title podría contener la palabra "Restaurant" y el campo city podría contener la palabra "Ciudad1" pero la palabra "en", que es un mero conector, no estará en ninguno, de modo que debiera ser un OR, cosa que si no pilla esa palabra, que simplemente se pase por alto dicho filtro.

Honestamente, no estoy seguro si la tecnología utilizada es la mejor para ese tipo de problemas. Si puedes, es mejor que se filtre por ciudad y aparte por título de la búsqueda.

Espero aportar

Comment: Gracias, realmente es lo que necesito... Sí entendiste. Ahora debo intenar con tu idea, me parece que sí funcionaría pero tengo la misma duda, no sé si sea la mejor manera de resolverlo. Pero inicialmente me lo resuelve. Gracias, te aviso si me funcionó.

Comment: Ánimo. Siempre se puede

Comment: Saludos hice unos cambios tomando en cuenta tu respuesta, edite la pregunta y coloque allí la información a ver si puedes ayudarme. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En base a la edición de tu pregunta se me ocurre que puedes hacer esto:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', street, ' ', city, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', price, ' ', province, ' ', region)"), "LIKE", "%$search[$i]%");
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', street, ' ', city, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', price, ' ', province, ' ', region)"), "LIKE", "%$search[$i]%");
          }

    }

    return $array;

}
```

Es un poco difícil sin probarlo pero mi idea consiste en lo siguiente:
1) Primero creamos un filtro que será el básico
2) Todos los demás filtros van con un orWhere

Lo que no estoy completamente seguro es si se están concatenando bien los where pero siempre puedes comprobar la query que te está generando con:

```
$query->toSql();
```